# Color not being applied from css

Tags: html, css

I have the following

HTML:

`<h1 class="largeTitle">Exikle</h1>`

CSS:

```
h1.largetitle {
    font-size: 9ee;
    color: #2B547E;
}
```

However the color does not get implemented. I believe the code is correct so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: 9em not 9ee as you have

Comment: Case sensitive...  Also 9em not 9ee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong class and attribute

Class name are casesensitive and font-size is `em` not `ee`

Try

```
h1.largeTitle {
    font-size: 9em;
    color: #2B547E;
}
```

Comment: Whereas capitalization does not count when it comes to *property* names, i.e. `cOlOr:`, it does count when it comes to *selectors*, i.e. `.className` or `div`

Answer (score 2):

CSS is case sensitive with selectors(IDs & Classes) so `h1.largetitle` should be `h1.largeTitle`.